# Site traffic fell off the table the week of May 10, 2022. What happened?

Tags: discussion, site-statistics

I looked into the [site analytics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) (25k+ rep only) just now and what I found was alarming.

[image]

Daily page views averaged between 50k and 60k consistently all year until about May 10th, when it just tanked.

Surely 75% of readers did not all decide to never visit the site again on the same day. What in the world is going on?

Comment: Did other metrics of site-usership *also* tank? I checked now, not even *close* to as much as views. I think a longer timescale image would actually help make your point *significantly*. April - Now seems like a good candidate

Comment: @Exempt-Medic Weirdly, no, not really.

Comment: @Exempt-Medic eating lunch, will update soon.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't check if this is the case for any *other* sites, but if anybody can, that would be very helpful

Comment: @Exempt-Medic See [this graph](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9225374#9225374) of SO in the tavern on meta.

Comment: Relevant MSE question: [Why has there been such a huge drop in "new visits" since May 9th, 2022, across multiple sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379047/335251)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is related to Stack Exchange recategorizing cookies. See Glorfindel’s answer to this meta.se question, [Why has there been such a huge drop in "new visits" since May 9th, 2022, across multiple sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379047/674198)

> Educated guess, by no means official:
>
> > We are committing to recategorizing the Google Analytics cookie as a “Performance Cookie” by May 13, 2022.
>
> (source: [this answer by staff member @CesarM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378440/295232) - the actual switch happened on [May 10th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374897/why-is-the-google-analytics-cookie-defined-as-strictly-necessary-and-saved-wit/378440#comment1264074_378440))
>
> The [site analytics](/site-analytics) are powered by Google Analytics, and if users don't accept the cookies, they don't get registered as new visits.